# autocommit and @Transactional and Cascading with spring, jpa and hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, orm, jpa

what I would like to accomplish is the following:

1. have autocommit enabled so per default all queries get commited
2. if there is a @Transactional on a method, it overrides the autocommit and encloses all queries into a single transaction, thus overriding the autocommit
3. if there is a @Transactional method that calls other @Transactional annotated methods, the outer most annotation should override the inner annotaions and create a larger transaction, thus annotations also override eachother

I am currently still learning about spring-orm and couldn't find documentation about this and don't have a test project for this yet.

So my questions are:

- What is the default behaviour of transactions in spring?
- If the default differs from my requirement, is there a way to configure my desired behaviour?
- Or is there a totally different best practice for transactions?

## --EDIT--

I have the following test-setup:

```
@javax.persistence.Entity
public class Entity {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Integer id;
  private String name;
  public Integer getId() {
    return id;
  }
  public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
  }
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }
  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}

@Repository
public class Dao {
  @PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager em;
  public void insert(Entity ent) {
    em.persist(ent);
  }
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public List<Entity> selectAll() {
    List<Entity> ents = em.createQuery("select e from " + Entity.class.getName() + " e").getResultList();
    return ents;
  }
}
```

If I have it like this, even with autocommit enabled in hibernate, the insert method does nothing. I have to add @Transactional to the insert or the method calling insert for it to work...

Is there a way to make @Transactional completely optional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you can't have queries without an active transaction in hibernate
- `@Transactional` has a `propagation` attribute, which identifies the transaction behaviour when new methods are called. The default is `REQUIRED`, which is what you want. [Here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.6/reference/transaction.html#tx-propagation) you can find a graphical presentation of the concept.
- you can omit using `@Transactional` if you set-up your transactional methods with aop, like this:

  ```
  <aop:config>
      <aop:pointcut id="serviceMethods"
          expression="execution(* com.company.product.service..*.*(..))" />
      <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="serviceMethods" />
  </aop:config>

  <tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
      <tx:attributes>
          <tx:method name="*" propagation="REQUIRED" />
      </tx:attributes>
  </tx:advice>
  ```

  That makes all public methods in the `service` package transactional.

Also, feel free to read the entire chapter on spring transactions.

Comment: hmm, ok that would work, seems like the idea I had about using autocommit was a bad idea anyway. I think it would be better practice for me to just annotate the services propertly. autocommit on any db operation would too easily lead to a broken state. instead of doing a blacklist approach I should go with a whitelist (metaphorical).
I will try to create an advice that adds @Transactional to all beans annotated with @Service. Though first read about spring-aop. :)

thanks

Comment: the advice for transactional was a bad idea afterall:
--
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-ts1.html?ca=dgr-jw22SafeJavaTrans&S_TACT=105AGX59&S_CMP=grsitejw22
--
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882959/spring-ioc-injecting-conrete-implementation-of-interface-to-test
--
my solution is to only annotate methods that do write operations and leave the rest not annotated. Adding propagation=SUPPORTS and readonly=true would maybe increase performance with hibernate, but that is currently too much effort for me to put into an aspectj CTW aspect.

Comment: I have just had problems like this, and found your reference to readOnly=true and propagation=SUPPORTS. Just a word of warning: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-ts1/index.html#N101B1 it doesn't work that way.